# I was roommates with him in college

Tags: word-choice

> But, uh, Ross is a great guy. I was roommates with him in college.

That's from Friends episode [S06E21]. Shouldn't it be

> we were roommates with him

Which sounds more natural?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When talking about a relationship we can in casual speech use a plural and say, for example "I was friends with him", or "I was roommates with him". These are possible:

Casual: Ross is a great guy. **I was** roommates with him in college.

More formal: Ross is a great guy. **We were** roommates in college.

Comment: Are you a native speaker of British English? Please let me know if you see my comment.

Answer (score 3):

No. You could say *We were roommates*, meaning you and him. But if you say *We were roommates with him* it unambiguously means "I and somebody else were roommates with him".

The original sentence may not make logical sense, but it is a perfectly normal way of saying it.

Comment: "Friends with" is another example. "I was friends with him".

Comment: Thank you both. That is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To complement the other answers, if using the first person past simple, *I was*, the most correct (formal) phrase would be:

> Ross is a great guy. I was his roommate at college